# Directive vs. service to share data from navigation panel

Tags: angularjs

I am confused about putting my navigation panel into directive or keep it as it is.

I have navigation panel in html template (I've call this template because it is in separate file and can be reused) which is included into main view by ng-include.
This template have separate controller and module. Main view that is invoked by ui-router also have separate controller. And now, I need to have some variable to store output of navigation template. And as far I understand, services are for sharing data between controllers.

But what if my navigation would be directive? I.e `<navigation ng-model="variable">`.
Then it would be declared in main view and variable would be visible for that view, without another entity(service) for sharing data.

Which approach is better?

Comment: My advice is this: if you are making a directive that ends up just loading a template, I would argue that should just be an ngInclude. If the template needs params, or operates on different sets of data, or needs context dependent behavior, then yes, it should rightfully be made into a directive with isolate scope for purposes of reuse. Services are the right way to share data period, whether between controllers, or directives, or controllers and directives. Think of the service more as the model.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should always keep your data in services. The `$stateParams` service that `ui-router` provides is probably what you want to use in this situation.

Take a look at the `ui-router` sample app.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/contacts/1

**Update**

A directive doesn't make much sense in this situation since you are already using `ui-router`. What you proposed would certainly work but you would be reimplementing something that `ui-router` already provides for you.

**Update 2**

Instead of using `ng-include` you could have an abstract state with 2 child `ui-view`s (1 for the navigation and 1 for the "body").

To keep all of the logic together you could put the logic in a service that is shared between the controllers.

**Update 3**

How the `ui-view`s are laid out should be determined by how your app flows and what parts of the UI change. The complexity of the component shouldn't force or prevent it from bing a separate `ui-view`. From a UI perspective you can think of a `ui-view` like an `iframe`. They help give structure and let you swap out their contents easily.

Now if a component is something that will be reused but in a different way each time (ie. a date picker or custom dropdown field) then it should be a directive.

Comment: Hm, I am thinking about this directive as some sort encapsulation, that gives me one place for component's code (output in service breaks this). And also with directive I can put directive to main view and share same controller. With templates approach I need communications between two controllers. But probably I will choose try $stateParams anyway.

Comment: But is it still possible to use ui-router with abstract view when state consist of main view i.e table of data, navigation panel that is not just links but checkboxes and maybe other panel with different options that affect what is displayed on main view? Each of component should be separate ui-view?